# User has_many Memberships and has_many Organizations through Memberships. How to specify default Membership?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'd like to give my users the ability to specify which Organization is their default Organization. Each user can belong to multiple Organizations, as shown below:

```
Class User
  has_many :memberships, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :organizations, through: :memberships, source: :organization
end

Class Organization
  has_many :memberships, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :memberships, source: :user
end

Class Membership
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :organization
end
```

What would be the most appropriate way to specify that an organization and/or membership is the users default? This way, I can display the default organizations feed when they log into the application.

I've tried adding a default boolean attribute to memberships, which seems to work but just doesn't feel right. I've considered adding a default_organization attribute to the User model, which would just hold the ID of the organization, but again that doesn't seem right.

Is there a Rails approved way of handling this?

Answer (score 0):

Thinking about it there are several ways you can approach this:

since this is a many to many association you can add a a field on the association model, but that needs some validation to work correctly since you can by mistake set more than one of those relations to true.

the other way is by setting a field to your user model like you described, its a little clunky but it would work.

the last way I can think, and I think is the best one is make a has_one relationship between the user and an organization. something like this:

```
has_one :organization, as: :default_organization
```

Hope it helped

Comment: Can you expand on this at all? I'm having trouble figuring out how to get this to work. I tried using the has_one :organization, as: :default_organization on the User model, but that looks for a default_organization_id in the organization model, which does not exist. Even if it did, how would that help identify the default for each user?